# How do I delete a cloud printer?

Tags: cloud, printing

I have 2 Google accounts.

When I was first hooking up cloud printing, I connected my printer with account A and then shared it with B.

I then realized that I preferred to have cloud printing go through account B.  I deleted the printer from account A and connected it to B.

I can now cloud print through account B, but the account A printer still shows up (greyed out).  Worse yet, it's the default printer.  So, every time that I cloud print, I have an extra 2 clicks.

How do I delete a cloud printer that it is no longer to be "shared" with me or, at least, change which cloud printer is the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete cloud printers through [this page](https://www.google.com/cloudprint/#printers). I've never been able to tell how defaults occur, though. It seems to mostly do it by what was used last, but randomly it doesn't. Sorry I can't give you a good answer on that part.